# Why am I having trouble accessing SSL certificates working with Node.js/Express-TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to switch a project's backend from JavaScript (Node.js/Express) to TypeScript, but I'm running through a rather bizarre issue. FS's readFileSync cant/wont access either key.pem or cert.pem files in the security folder (same project level as the server.ts file), which have been generated for localhost https. This works just fine in my original app, so what am I missing switching to TS?

Here's the relevant code snippet.

```
import * as https from 'https';
import * as fs from 'fs';

import app from './app';
import { PORT } from './config';

const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./security/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT);
})
```

Below is a shot of the error message thrown.

[image]

Comment: can you try giving a full path once? Just to check if its a pathing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your compiled TypeScript code is not located somewhere, where relative path with dot symbol would work. Your TS sources might be in the root folder, and there's also `security` folder here. But there's no `security` folder in the build folder, which contains JS.

Use Node's `path` native module or put `security` folder into the build.

Comment: Yup! Prepending __dirname to the files' path did the trick. Thanks for the suggestion.